# Projective homologies

Tags: linear-algebra, projective-geometry, projective-space

In a projective plane (i.e. two-dimensional) $\mathbb P$, we call a general homology a projective transformation $h:\mathbb P\to\mathbb P$ such that $h$ has a line of fixed points $L$ called the *axis* of $h$, a fixed point $O\not\in L$ called the *center* of $h$ and has the property that any line through $O$ is invariant under $h$. How should one study the possible situations that can arise with the composition $h\circ g$ of two general homologies with the same center $O$, and different axes $L$ and $R$.

Should I try to analyze this geometrically? (since it's the plane, certain representative drawings are possible, which are then backed by algebraic considerations), or should I use pure algebra and consider different Jordan form, bases, etc. configurations? I know the question is general so any single case study would be a great answer.

Comment: You should do whatever it is that works best for you!

Comment: (To find out *what* works best for you, you have to do both things for a while, of course)

Comment: As a general rule, whenever you know how to do something in two different ways, you should do it in two different ways. That is the only way to gauge which one of the two worrks best in which situations. How else are you going to find out? That proceeding purely algebraically is posssibly what works best *for me* is of absolutely no importance to you.

Comment: (And whenever you only know one way to do something, you should strive to find another way, for it is quite possible that the method you know does not work best in all possible situations... So even after solving whatever problem you have using the methd you know, that does not mean you are done)

Comment: Since the axes are different, you have immediately two fixed points of $h\circ g$, namely $O$ and $L\cap R$. This definitely narrows down the situation. But then I find no geometric way to proceed. I have to proceed algebraically...to see that the composition is also a homology with the same center.

Comment: @TroyWoo Wow, I had forgotten about this one! Maybe I'll try to solve it now then :)